# how to use Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA to count sheets from 1 to 31

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

need help with that > i try to use how to use
`Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA` to count sheets from 1 to 31

i can't do it ..  any help

that what i try :

```
number = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("1:31"))
```

Full code:

```
Private Sub btnclone_Click()

Dim counter As Integer
Dim number As Long

number = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("1:31"))

 For counter = 1 To number Step 4
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NAME").Select
    Range("tblA[[CIVIL ID]:[LOCATION]]").Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NAME").Select
    Range("tblB[[CIVIL ID]:[LOCATION]]").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Select
    With Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    With .Areas
        With .Item(.Count)
            With .Cells
                .Item(.Cells.Count).Offset(1, 0).Select
            End With
        End With
    End With
End With
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    Next counter

End Sub
```

thanks for any help

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to count. If it is truly the 'number of worksheets' in the workbook, what is the point of limiting it to 31? CountA counts cells in a range, not worksheets.  Give an example of what you are trying to do

Comment: that's right . i am trying to count a worksheets .. and from you comment i think it's not possible

Comment: Looking at your full code - it doesn't seem the main problem is counting the sheets.  From what I can tell - copy part (or all?) of `tblA` from the sheet called `NAME`, paste it into `A2` of a sheet called `1`.  Back to `Name` sheet, copy `tblB` paste it beneath `tblA`, or add the data to `tblA`?  Not sure where the count of sheets is relevant.

Comment: Are you sure you want to count sheets and not tables? Looks like you're trying to combine all tables on the `Name` sheet to a table on the `1` sheet.  Note:  `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Select` selects the sheet called `1`, while `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select` selects the first sheet in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Excel Adjacent Table Columns

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnclone_Click()
    CopyTableColumns
End Sub

Sub CopyTableColumns()

    Const sName As String = "NAME"
    Const sCols1 As String = "tblA[[CIVIL ID]:[LOCATION]]"
    Const sCols2 As String = "tblB[[CIVIL ID]:[LOCATION]]"
    
    Const dfCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const dFirst As Long = 1
    Const dStep As Long = 4
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg1 As Range: Set srg1 = sws.Range(sCols1)
    Dim srg2 As Range: Set srg2 = sws.Range(sCols2)
    
    Dim rCount1 As Long: rCount1 = srg1.Rows.Count
    Dim rCount2 As Long: rCount2 = srg2.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg1.Columns.Count
    
    Dim dLast As Long: dLast = GetHighestSheet(wb)
    If dLast < dFirst Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim dfrrg As Range
    Dim d As Long
    
    For d = dFirst To dLast Step dStep
        On Error Resume Next
            Set dws = wb.Worksheets(CStr(d))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not dws Is Nothing Then
            Set dfrrg = dws.Range(dfCellAddress).Resize(, cCount)
            Set drg = dfrrg.Resize(rCount1)
            drg.Value = srg1.Value
            Set drg = drg.Resize(rCount2).Offset(rCount1)
            drg.Value = srg2.Value
            Set dws = Nothing
        End If
    Next d

End Sub

Function GetHighestSheet( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook) _
As Long
    
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim CurrentNum As Long
    Dim MaxNum As Long
    
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If IsNumeric(sh.Name) Then
            CurrentNum = CLng(sh.Name)
            If CurrentNum > GetHighestSheet Then GetHighestSheet = CurrentNum
        End If
    Next sh
    
End Function
```

Comment: VBasic2008 ... thaaaaaanks to the sky .. that work like magic .. you save my day

Answer (score 1):

In VBA `Thisworkbook.Worksheets.Count` gives you the number of worksheets in the workbook where the VBA is running.

Answer (score 0):

what im try to do is :

copy tableA to sheets(1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29)
then
copy tableB to same sheets after finding th last row ( under tableA)

that's all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).